# remove duplicate from dataframe base on some conditions

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have to remove duplicate time with the below conditions in the same time entries check status if all are "n" take anyone and remove other else check lowest Id among duplicated rows if the lowest Id have status "n" take other entry.

I have more than 200000 rows.

[image: example data]

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['Id', 'status', 'time']
records = [
  [1,'n',5],
  [2,'n',5],
  [3,'n',5],
  [4,'n',6],
  [5,'w',6],
  [6,'w',7],
  [7,'r',8],
  [8,'n',9],
]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=columns)
```

[image: expected output]

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['Id', 'status', 'time']
records = [
  [1,'n',5],
  [5,'w',6],
  [6,'w',7],
  [7,'r',8],
  [8,'n',9],
]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=columns)
```

Comment: It's recommended to add your data as text, we can not copy the contents from image.

Comment: updated question with example and output data

Answer (score 1):

First separate out the rows that do not have  duplicates for `time` column, then, apply the logic of selecting duplicate values `grouping` the duplicates by `time`, then taking the required rows i.e. minmum `Id` if all the `status` values equal `n`, otherwise taking the minimum `Id` where `status` is not equal to `n`, then concatenate both the duplicate and non-duplicate dataframes. You can sort the values at last by `Id`, if you need it

```py
duplicates = df.duplicated(subset=['time'], keep=False)
out = (pd.concat([df[~duplicates],
                df[duplicates]
               .groupby('time')
               .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Id'].idxmin()] 
                            if (x['status']=='n').all() 
                            else x.loc[x[x['status'].ne('n')]['Id'].idxmin()])], 
               ignore_index=True)
 ).sort_values(['Id'])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   Id status  time
3   1      n     5
4   5      w     6
0   6      w     7
1   7      r     8
2   8      n     9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# 1. make colum ncount (count the number of status=='n' by time) 

df.loc[df['status']=='n','ncount'], df.loc[df['status']!='n','ncount']=1,0
df['ncount']=df['ncount'].groupby(df['time']).cumsum()
df=df.sort_values(['time','ncount'],ascending=False)
df['ncount']=df['ncount'].groupby(df['time']).cummax()
df=df.sort_index()

print(df)

# 2.1 condition 1( current observation by time)

con1=df.groupby('time').cumcount().add(1)
print(con1)

# 2.2 condition 2(the number of observation by time)

con2=df.groupby('time').cumcount(ascending=False).groupby(df['time']).cummax().add(1)
print(con2)

# 3. keep observations

out=df.loc[((df['ncount']==con2) & (con1==1) & (con2>1)) |
          ((df['ncount']!=con2) & (con1==con2) & (con2>1)) |
          (con2==1),:].drop(columns='ncount')

print(out)
#   Id status  time
#0   1      n     5
#4   5      w     6
#5   6      w     7
#6   7      r     8
#7   8      n     9
```

I also made your how to datawork in Stata...

```
clear
edit

* 0) make dataset

input Id str1(status) time
1 "n" 5
2 "n" 5
3 "n" 5
4 "n" 6
5 "w" 6
6 "w" 7
7 "r" 8
8 "n" 9
end

list ,sep(0)

/*

     +--------------------+
     | Id   status   time |
     |--------------------|
  1. |  1        n      5 |
  2. |  2        n      5 |
  3. |  3        n      5 |
  4. |  4        n      6 |
  5. |  5        w      6 |
  6. |  6        w      7 |
  7. |  7        r      8 |
  8. |  8        n      9 |
     +--------------------+


*/


* 1) generate ncount column(count the number of n by time)

bysort time (Id): egen ncount=count(Id) if status=="n"
by time : replace ncount=ncount[_n-1] if missing(ncount)
list ,sepby(time)

/*

     +-----------------------------+
     | Id   status   time   ncount |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. |  1        n      5        3 |
  2. |  2        n      5        3 |
  3. |  3        n      5        3 |
     |-----------------------------|
  4. |  4        n      6        1 |
  5. |  5        w      6        1 |
     |-----------------------------|
  6. |  6        w      7        . |
     |-----------------------------|
  7. |  7        r      8        . |
     |-----------------------------|
  8. |  8        n      9        1 |
     +-----------------------------+



*/




* 2) keep observations(_n: current observation, _N: the number of observation)

by time: keep if _N==1 | _N!=1 & ncount==_N & _n==1 | ///
                 _N!=1 & ncount!=_N & _n==_N
drop ncount
list ,sep(0)


/*

     +--------------------+
     | Id   status   time |
     |--------------------|
  1. |  1        n      5 |
  2. |  5        w      6 |
  3. |  6        w      7 |
  4. |  7        r      8 |
  5. |  8        n      9 |
     +--------------------+


*/
```